# How to send <textarea> text to python view in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a textview in my html template that allows the user to enter text

```
<textarea  name="texteditor" id="texteditor" style="width:100%; height:100vh; resize:none; font-size:20px; font-family:sans-serif; border:none;" placeholder="Start Writing!"></textarea>
```

I want to get that text on a button click into my view

```
def write_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    texteditor = request.POST.get('texteditor')
    print(texteditor)
    return render(request, "write.html", {'texteditor': texteditor})
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: put textarea inside a form and do form submit on button click

Comment: Do you want the text to be sent in realtime or after submit button is pressed? If it is later then please show the full form and especially the information on the submit button.

Comment: @Amit I want to do it in realtime

Comment: ok.. what is the url for write_view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ajax for this.

Add this script in your html file. I have assumed that the url for write_view (in your views.py) is 'url_to_post'. Change it below to suit your requirements.

```
<script>
   $("#texteditor").keyup(function(event){
   TextEntered = $("#texteditor").val();
   // You can remove the below line, after debugging!
   console.log("You have typed the following ",TextEntered);
   // You can remove the above line, after debugging!
   data = {
'TextEntered':TextEntered, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
          };
   $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:url_to_post,
           datatype: 'JSON',
           data: data,
           success: Successfully_Received
  })
})

function Successfully_Received(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  console.log("Successfully received by View and acknowledged");
}
</script>
```

Then I will change your views.py function like below.

```py
def write_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        texteditor = request.POST['TextEntered']
        print(texteditor)
##      Don't forget to do validation and cleanup on texteditor to avoid security hassles  
##      Do your logic here
        SuccessAcknowledgment = {"Acknowledged":"Acknowledged"}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(SuccessAcknowledgment))
    else:
        return render(request, "write.html")
```

This is my guesstimate solution, without seeing your code in entirety. Please let me know, if it worked out or not. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Amit! I tried to run your code but I get a 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined' and my terminal doesn't print any output. And the url is write/ to go to my html file.

Comment: Please download Jquery and put in your static folder (along with other js file). Then import into html as you will normally import a JavaScript.

Comment: Just to be sure! I download jquery into my templates folder inside my project

Comment: No static folder

Comment: Please see your settings.py .. it will tell you where is the static folder supposed to be. If it is not there then you will have to create it and then put the jquery and JavaScript files there

Comment: Ok, I have it now! The ReferenceError has vanished, but I still can't get my terminal to print the string

Comment: Would it be better if I shared all my code with you?

Comment: Yes. No problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Here are the files that added to a GitHub repo. https://github.com/PedroVictorCoding/dummy-project

Comment: I was able to figure it and your code worked! THANK YOU

Comment: Ok. I am sorry. I was very busy for last two days. Didn't have chance to look at your code. I am glad that it worked out for you. All the best.